# Kubernetes Cluster with finished jobs unstable; kubelet logs filled with "http2: no cached connection was available"

Tags: ubuntu, go, kubernetes, kubelet

#### Summary

I have various single-node Kubernetes clusters which become unstable after having accumulated ~300 completed jobs.

In one cluster, for example, there are 303 completed jobs:

```
root@xxxx:/home/xxxx# kubectl get jobs | wc -l
303
```

#### Observations

What I observe is that

- The `kubelet` logs are filled with error messages like this: `kubelet[877]: E0219 09:06:14.637045     877 reflector.go:134] object-"default"/"job-162273560": Failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get https://172.13.13.13:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Djob-162273560&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: http2: no cached connection was available`
- The node status is not being updated, with a similar error message:
  `kubelet[877]: E0219 09:32:57.379751     877 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://172.13.13.13:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dxxxxx&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: http2: no cached connection was available`
- Eventually, the node is being marked as `NotReady` and no new pods are scheduled

  `NAME    STATUS     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
  xxxxx   NotReady   master   6d4h   v1.12.1`
- The cluster is entering and exiting the master disruption mode (from the `kube-controller-manager` logs): 

  `I0219 09:29:46.875397       1 node_lifecycle_controller.go:1015] Controller detected that all Nodes are not-Ready. Entering master disruption mode.
  I0219 09:30:16.877715       1 node_lifecycle_controller.go:1042] Controller detected that some Nodes are Ready. Exiting master disruption mode.`

The real culprit appears to be the `http2: no cached connection was available` error message. The only real references I've found are a couple of issues in the Go repository (like [#16582](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16582)), which appear to have been fixed a long time ago.

In most cases, deleting the completed jobs seems to restore the system stability.

#### Minimal repro (tbc)

I seem to be able to reproduce this problem by creating lots of jobs which use containers which mount ConfigMaps:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: job-%JOB_ID%
data:
# Just some sample data
  game.properties: |
    enemies=aliens
    lives=3
    enemies.cheat=true
    enemies.cheat.level=noGoodRotten
    secret.code.passphrase=UUDDLRLRBABAS
    secret.code.allowed=true
    secret.code.lives=30
  ui.properties: |
    color.good=purple
    color.bad=yellow
    allow.textmode=true
    how.nice.to.look=fairlyNice
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-%JOB_ID%
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(20)"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/config
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: job-%JOB_ID%
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Schedule lots of these jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 100 399`;
do
    cat job.yaml | sed "s/%JOB_ID%/$i/g" | kubectl create -f -
    sleep 0.1
done
```

#### Questions

I'm very curious though as to what causes this problem, as 300 completed jobs seems to be a fairly low number.

Is this a configuration problem in my cluster? A possible bug in Kubernetes/Go? Anything else that I can try?

Comment: I followed ur steps and in no scenario I am getting any errors. Used Minikube v1.10, Compute Engine v1.13 and CE v1.12.1 all as single node cluster (master is the node). Only thing I spotted in minikube was `Error from server: error when creating "STDIN": etcdserver: request timed out` but I was able to easily reach 400, 500 jobs completed. So there has to be other problem, can you provide more details - what else is going on in the cluster? How did you deploy it and where? Do you have any tolerations, requests/limits set? Also please provide `kubectl describe node master_name`

Comment: That's odd, I can consistently reproduce this in a Vagrant environment. I've uploaded the script I use to provision the environment to https://github.com/qmfrederik/k8s-job-repro.

It uses a custom Ansible role to provision the VM, but it's pretty standard Kubernetes. I've noticed the problem does not reproduce with Kubernetes v1.11 but does with v1.12 and v1.13.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74302 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74412 describe this in further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize this problem and why does it happen. It has been actually an issue related to 1.12 and 1.13. As explained in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74412) (probably created by author) this seems to be an issue of http2 connection pool implementing, or as explained in one of the comments it is a connection management problem in kubelet. Described ways of mitigating can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74412#issuecomment-468437599). and if you would need more information all links are avaliable in the linked GitHub issue.